# UICollectionViewCell With automatic sizing not Working in iOS 9 But Working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to make dynamic size of UICollectionViewCell.

It's Working on **iOS 10** but app is crash in **iOS 9**.

I have tried many solutions but none works.

Screen Shot of iPhone 5s (Working)
[image]

**I Want the above output on iOS 9**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell"];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout =  (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 8.0f;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8.0f;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataArr.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblText.text = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Error log

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' *** First throw call stack: (0x2592791b 0x250c2e17 0x2583972b 0x2a6faba7 0x2a6b8adf 0x2a698753 0x2a698d87 0x29f08d57 0x29f06ed3 0x29f01fe9 0x29e9ea73 0x27f36bcd 0x27f32375 0x27f32209 0x27f316d1 0x27f313a5 0x29e95b79 0x258e96c9 0x258e79cd 0x258e7dff 0x25837229 0x25837015 0x26e27ac9 0x29f0b189 0x66f2d 0x254df873) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Please add error log and show which line did you got crash

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2592791b 0x250c2e17 0x2583972b 0x2a6faba7 0x2a6b8adf 0x2a698753 0x2a698d87 0x29f08d57 0x29f06ed3 0x29f01fe9 0x29e9ea73 0x27f36bcd 0x27f32375 0x27f32209 0x27f316d1 0x27f313a5 0x29e95b79 0x258e96c9 0x258e79cd 0x258e7dff 0x25837229 0x25837015 0x26e27ac9 0x29f0b189 0x66f2d 0x254df873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: It crash after return cell

Comment: Can you show where did you initialize `dataArr` and where did you change it?

Comment: dataArr value set on viewDidLoad

Comment: I don't see it on `viewDidLoad` method

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved in that some change in Code and implement some method that is available in given code.

1) implement **intrinsicContentSize** method in CustomeCollectionViewCell

2) set value of **tempCell** from that get size in **sizeForItemAtIndexPath** method

**CustomeCollectionViewCell.m**

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = self.lblText.intrinsicContentSize;
    size.width += 48;   // add padding Width that Given in Cell
    size.height += 32;  // add padding Height
    return size;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomeCollectionViewCell *tempCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataArr;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataArr = @[@"a",@"bc",@"def",@"ghijkl",@"mkopqrst",@"uvwxyz"];
    self.tempCell = (CustomeCollectionViewCell*) [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@“CustomeCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];

    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataArr.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomeCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblText.text = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.tempCell.lblText.text = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return self.tempCell.intrinsicContentSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}
```